# Define global configuration variables in KMM

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

In native android project, we can define BuildConfig variables which can be change based on the selected build type (debug or release). For this we can add the code below in app level gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField 'String', "BASE_URL", '"https://stackoverflow.com/"'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'String', "BASE_URL", '"https://qa.stackoverflow.com/"'
    }
}
```

I am looking forward to create global configuration variables like this can be accessed from shared module and from Android and iOS module if possible. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you solved this? Thank you.

Comment: Back then there wasn't any platform support. I am not sure about now.

Answer (score 8):

You could check out [BuildKonfig](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig)

For an example:

```
buildkonfig {
    packageName = "com.halcyonmobile.multiplatformplayground"
    val baseUrl = "baseUrl"
    defaultConfigs {
        buildConfigField(
            Type.STRING,
            baseUrl,
            "https://halcyon-multiplatform-backend.herokuapp.com/"
        )
    }
    defaultConfigs("dev") {
        buildConfigField(Type.STRING, baseUrl, "http://0.0.0.0:8080/")
    }
}
```

(Example from https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/common/build.gradle.kts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen this library but I am looking for platform support for this common use case.

Comment: @CodeCameo there isn't platform support yet

Comment: Thank you @RóbertNagy for this ‍♂️!!! Glad you shared it. It's really nice that someone is contributing with adding this support before there's something in KMM for it.